# Ids must exist in the Container or as a generated column

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm developing an vaadin application, and now I'm not able to resolve the following problem.

I have my object model:

```
public class MyModel {

    private long id;
    private Date dValidoAl;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDValidoAl() {
        return dValidoAl;
    }

    public void setDValidoAl(Date dValidoAl) {
        this.dValidoAl = dValidoAl;
    }

}
```

Now I'm trying to bind this object to a `BeanItemContainer` in this way:

```
Table table = new Table();
BeanItemContainer<MyModel> container = new BeanItemContainer<MyModel>(MyModel.class);
table.setContainerDataSource(container);

Object[] visibleProperties = new Object[] { "id", "dValidoAl" };
String[] columnsHeader = new String[] { "Id", "Inizio Validità" };
table.setVisibleColumns(visibleProperties);
table.setColumnHeaders(columnsHeader);
```

but I get this error:

> Ids must exist in the Container or as a generated column, missing id: dValidoAl

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `tableContainer.getContainerPropertyIds()` return? Is `dValidoAl` there?

Comment: I found DValidoAl instead of dValidoAl in tableContainer.getContainerPropertyIds() and I changed the name of property "dValidoAl" with "DValidoAl" and now everything works. Thanks

Comment: @Skizzo Please post your solution as an answer and accept it! Thanks!

Comment: The [documentation](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/datamodel.container.html) says, that the porpertyIDs are created by inspecting the getter and settters. (Eg. setUserName(String name) / getUsername() leads to property ID "userName")

Answer (score 1):

As @Skizzo posted, and as defined in the [Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/datamodel.container.html), the BeanItemContainer (implementation of BeanContainer) will take as PropertyIds inspecting the getters and setters.

> The item properties are determined automatically by inspecting the
> getter and setter methods of the class. This requires that the bean
> class has public visibility, local classes for example are not
> allowed. Only beans of the same type can be added to the container.

In this case, applying DValidoAl as the propertyId of the container you can do the operations you need.